# ActiveJob throwing error in main

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activejob

Earlier I was using, DelayedJobs, so whatever the exception is being thrown it never crashes server from running.

But after I moved to active jobs, exceptions are thrown in browser itself, and server crashes.

Is the active job not running in background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you're using the `inline` queue adapter which will immediately execute the job. 
See [the documentation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/QueueAdapters.html) for a full list of supported backends for asynchronous execution. Since you're already familiar with Delayed Job, I'd recommend using that but there's no need to do so. Sidekiq and others are very nice, too.